# Delete comment with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

What is the best possible way/results using a link a div and ajax to pass data without a page refresh. I'm wanting my comments and div to fade out when clicked and don't want the page to refresh. So it stays exactly where I delete the comment.

I've tried this, but its not working

```
   <script>
function delete_(pid){
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "include/post.delete.php",
   data: "pid="+pid,
   success: function(){
   $("#comment-"+pid).remove();
   }
 });
}
</script>
<? if($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']==$_SESSION['id']){
echo "<div style='cursor:pointer;' onclick=\"delete_('".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."');\">Delete comment</div>";
```

But it's not giving me the above results I need. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I need help if possible.

Comment: What results *is* it giving you?

Comment: Its deleting, but the page is just refreshing, and taking me back to the top. So it works. But I'd like it to delete the comment exactly where it is without refreshing the page and fade the div out if possible.

Comment: The JavaScript code you posted above can't be the reason for that. There's a form at the end of your HTML code, though, is this submitted to delete the comment? You will have to do this with JavaScript (i.e. no form submission)...

Comment: That is to delete the comment yeah.
How can I change it to make it work? Thanks for your help its appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, just corrected my comment, I've overlooked something in your code. Make sure you don't submit the form and check if the AJAX call works properly. See my answer below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a form with a submit action to delete that comment. When submitting a form, the page is automatically reloaded. Instead use a simple element with an `onclick` handler to trigger the AJAX request:

```
<div onclick="delete_('anyID');">Delete comment</div>
```

**EDIT:** Example:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function delete_(pid){
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "include/post.delete.php",
   data: "pid="+pid,
   success: function(){
   $("#comment-"+pid).remove();
   }
 });
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="comment-123">This is a comment.</div>
<div onclick="delete_('123');">Delete comment</div>
</body>
```

Comment: So I remove the complete form and replace it with the above trigger?

Comment: Yeah, I'd suggest that. I didn't fully understand your code as it's a bit cluttered, but if you don't want the page to refresh, you must get rid of the form (or rather of the form submission event). ;)

Comment: I've updated my oringinal post with what you suggested above..Its not working. :/

Comment: You may want to consider using a form as then your site can continue working with JS disabled. If JS is enabled, you can add a submit handler to the form and submit via AJAX.

Comment: Thank you. Will give it a bash

Comment: I have 2 different people saying two different things..Do I use a form or don't I?

Comment: Well, Michael Mior is right and I myself would do it exactly as he suggested. Although before experimenting with submit handlers on forms, imho you should first get the AJAX request working; you can still extend that later on.

Comment: Here's the example from above, this time with forms. Hope I don't confuse you. ;) http://pastie.org/4258448

Comment: My apologies. I forgot to add the comment-'ID' into the div. That is all that was wrong. Thank you all for your time and patience with me. I have now got what I needed. Thanks

Comment: Awesome post, really helpful to users doing searches for this information.